# Application that replaces the default windows authentication system

Tags: visual-c++, authentication

I want to write an application, which will replace the default authentication system in windows ( username and password). The new system ask for one or more extra field along with username, password. And this data will be sent to a server like system connected in network. And if that system ( stores all the authentication data ) validates the info received, it will send "yes".

Then only the client side application pass the authentication and allow to login. Can you help in doing this using VC++. Thanks in advance for your valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

The [Novell NetWare Client for Windows XP/2000](http://www.novell.com/products/clients/windows/xp2000/overview.html) provides a single, synchronized login to the Windows XP or Windows 2000 desktop and the NetWare network; users have to enter their names and passwords only once to access all the resources they are authorized to use.

So, it's possible to supplement the Windows login process.  Probably not very easy, but possible.

It would probably be cheaper to purchase Novell NetWare.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply Gilbert. Yeah it is possible, to supplement the Windows Login. I had seen couple of applications like that. Yeah I can use the netware, Just want to know how it can be done. If possible, can implement our own login system. folks pls help..